# Issue with booting kernel over 5.15.0-47 ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04

So I have an issue with kernel update. I am running kernel `5.15.0-47-generic` and tried to update it to `5.15.0-48-generic` and even to `5.19.5-051905-generic`. I used Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer for it. It seems to be installed on my system, but when I want to chose either of them to boot i get this:

```
error: bad shim signature.
error: you need to load kernel first.
press any key to continue...
```

I can only load `5.15.0-47-generic` and nothing else. 
(I didn't find anything similar in other threads so that's why I am asking. Thanks)

Comment: You will need to disable secure-boot in BIOS to use mainline and non-standard kernels.

Comment: @doug-smythies thanks for your answer. After I disable it is there going to be a problem with security? I mean - can I run on this setting for good?

Comment: See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235042/how-much-security-is-provided-by-secure-boot). I do not use secure boot.

Comment: Great! Thanks for that @DougSmythies. I booted kernel 5.19!

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable secure boot from BIOS